# Returning JSONP from Symfony2 controller using AJAX call

Tags: json, symfony, jsonp

I'm trying to return JSONP from Symfony2. I can return a regular JSON response fine, but it seems as if the JSON response class is ignoring my callback.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: true,
        jsonpCallback: 'callback',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',                      
        success: function(data) 
        {                                   
              console.log(data);
        },
        error: function() 
        {
            console.log('failed');
        }
        });
```

Then in my controller:

```
$callback = $request->get('callback');    
$response = new JsonResponse($result, 200, array(), $callback);
return $response;
```

The response I get from this is always regular JSON. No callback wrapping.

The Json Response class is here:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.php

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the docs says:

```
$response = new JsonResponse($result, 200, array(), $callback);
```

You're setting the callback method as the `$headers` parameter.

So you need to:

```
$response = new JsonResponse($result, 200, array());
$response->setCallback($callback);
return $response;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `JsonResponse`'s constructor doesn't take the callback argument. You need to set it via a method call:

```php
$response = new JsonResponse($result);
$response->setCallback($callback);

return $response;
```